# Add modifiers to duplicate elements in Lodash.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

The input will be a list with duplicate elements like this:

`['30','10','10','20','20','30']`

And the output will be a list with modified elements like this:

`['30#1', '10#1', '10#2', '20#1', '20#2', '30#2']`

The `#` modifier indicates the time for this element to appear in the list..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the result to be an array with an item that corresponds to each item in the original array. That's a job for `Array.prototype.map`. You want to keep a running count of how many times each item has appeared, which you can do with a simple object. In every iteration you look up the number of times the item has appeared and add one. Store that number as the new count and use it to build your return value. Like this, more or less:

```
var arr = ['30', '10', '10', '20', '20', '30'];
var counts = {};

var arr2 = arr.map(function(item) {
  counts[item] = (counts[item] || 0) + 1;
  return item + "#" + counts[item];
});
```

You don't need Lodash for this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using lodash.

```
_.map(coll, function(item) {
    return item + '#' +
        _.set(this, item, _.get(this, item, 0) + 1)[item];
}, {});
```

What's nice is that you don't need to setup temporary variables here to compute your result. The idea is to store them in `this` - the empty object that's passed to [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map).

The [get()](https://lodash.com/docs#get) function provides you with the 0 default if the property doesn't exist. So this can be used directly with [set()](https://lodash.com/docs#set), which sets the property value, and returns the object.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
var count = {};
['30','10','10','20','20','30'].map(function(current) {
    count[current] ? count[current] +=1 : count[current] = 1;
    return current + '#' + count[current];
})
```